# AM GM inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

[image]

For the above question, I remember there used to be an approach called "similarity" or "covergence" in my local language, not sure what it is called generally. Basically, it is a fast paced method for solving such questions where you have to find a minimum value.

Since, AM = GM if and only if every number in the list is the same (in which case all are equal). We make every term same, and then a get an integral value 'K' for the expression. Since our assumption was that they are equal, but in actual they are not, so we conclude that the expression must be > K.

Now, I can't seem to use that method effectively over here. Kindly help me with it please, I am trying to solve it without going the long winded approach of writing down AM >= GM terms, and solving for it.

Comment: Hint: $\;\frac{2x^2+6x+2}{x} = 2\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)+6 \ge \dots$

Comment: @dxiv You're the boss. 10 it should be for this, and 1000 for the whole expression. Thanks man. :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Feel free to fill-in the blanks and post a self-answer.

Comment: Haha, I would have loved to. But, I still do not know how to write the numbers, and equations in MathJax, perhaps the reason mods are troubled so much by my question edits. Because I've my exam coming up, I guess I'll learn the syntax a few months later and then would love to help folks here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x^2+3x+1}{x}.$
Then $ f'(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}.$
So $ f'(x)$ attains minimum at $x=1$ (x is +ve ) (one can check the sign of $f''(1)$ for completeness of the answer) and
$f(1)=5.$  The given function is
$g(xyz)=   2  f(x). 2f(y).2f(z).$
Therefore the minimum value of   $g(xyz)$    is
$2.5.2.5.2.5=1000.$

Answer (score 3):

Just converting @dxiv's comment to an answer, for completeness.

We have $$\frac{(2x^2 + 6x + 2)(2y^2 + 6y + 2)(2z^2 + 6z + 2)}{xyz} = \left(2x + \frac{2}{x} + 6 \right)\left(2y + \frac{2}{y} + 6 \right)\left(2z + \frac{2}{z} + 6 \right)$$
and $$2x + \frac{2}{x} + 6 \ge 6 + 4 = 10$$
by the AM-GM inequality applied to $2x$ and $\frac2x$. The minimum is attained at $x = 1$. Therefore, $$\left(2x + \frac{2}{x} + 6 \right)\left(2y + \frac{2}{y} + 6 \right)\left(2z + \frac{2}{z} + 6 \right) \ge 1000$$
and the minimum is attained at $x = y = z= 1$.